# vbscript to get email address and subject of sender in excel

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am very new to vbscript. My task is to create an excel sheet whenever the new mail comes in . I just want new excel and it should have only 2 fields Subject and Sender. That too only the most recent record .

Any help in this direction is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To handle new mail items you can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class or just create a rule and then assign a macro sub to run when the rule is triggered. The VBA macro should look like the following one:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
    ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

Then you can automate Excel to get the job done. I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.